# Не работает выборка из массива сессий PHP

Tags: php, сессия, redbeanphp

такой код работает, выдаёт массив:

```php
var_dump($_SESSION['logged_user']);
```

выдает он:

```php
object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (11) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(19) "RedBeanPHP\OODBBean" ["properties":protected]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["login"]=> string(7) "Likel0v" ["email"]=> string(20) "likel0vsky@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$P107YiTgSWDkifFN7B/Bxe7xWnE06MY1WnnRup/2fPSV0UFtOOaT2" } ["__info":protected]=> array(8) { ["type"]=> string(5) "users" ["sys.id"]=> string(2) "id" ["sys.orig"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["login"]=> string(7) "Likel0v" ["email"]=> string(20) "likel0vsky@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(60) "$2y$10$P107YiTgSWDkifFN7B/Bxe7xWnE06MY1WnnRup/2fPSV0UFtOOaT2" } ["tainted"]=> bool(false) ["changed"]=> bool(false) ["changelist"]=> array(0) { } ["model"]=> NULL ["data.bundle"]=> array(0) { } } ["beanHelper":protected]=> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#2 (1) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(44) "RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper" } ["fetchType":protected]=> NULL ["withSql":protected]=> string(0) "" ["withParams":protected]=> array(0) { } ["aliasName":protected]=> NULL ["via":protected]=> NULL ["noLoad":protected]=> bool(false) ["all":protected]=> bool(false) }
```

а такой не работает:

```php
var_dump($_SESSION['logged_user']->login);
```

выдает:

```
NULL
```

В чем проблема?

Версия PHP: 7.1
Для БД юзал redbeanphp.

Comment: `$_SESSION['logged_user']->getLogin()` ???

Comment: @ArchDemon нет, там именно массив с данными, которые не извлекаются по ключу

Comment: А что в докуменатции пишут? Наверняка сначала необходимо каким-то методом вытащить эти данные. А потом обращаться к ним.

Comment: @doox911 я на других своих сайтах делал так, все работало...

Comment: Не надо мне лечить про массив. `var_dump` вам чётко и ясно даёт понять, что это не массив